# missing input in this python script

Tags: python

im new to the language programme python 
I was given a task to find out the appropriate input that will result in a correct validation
here is the script:

```
import sys

def main():
  if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print ("Invalid args")
  return
  password = sys.argv[1]
  builder = 0
  for c in password:
    builder += ord(c)
  if builder == 1000 and len(password) == 10 and ord(password[1]) == 104:
    print ("correct")
  else:
    print ("incorrect")

  if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    main()
```

Comment: Check your indentation

Comment: Use the function ```chr()``` which is the inversion of ```ord()``` One solution would be ```dhddddddca``` but there are many more

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) What you've got is basically a math problem that also involves Unicode. What specifically are you having difficulty with? We're not going to just give you the answer, though it's piqued my curiosity and I'll probably try it for myself.

Comment: Some python advices: like what you did in ```if __name__ == ("__main__"):```, every time that you put ':' in python you should add a new identation block. So, in your code, def main(): should mean that everything that is in the main function has an identation. The same goes to ```for ... :``` and if-else statements. Also, if you want your code to break in certain point and return nothing, you can just write 'return -1' or something like this, This way you can identify which return the program has chose and helps in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You should look to the man of the function in this script [ord()](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#ord) [len()](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#len) and you should also indent the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly fine (apart from your indentation). The expected validated input though is rather wierd. You can try 'lhngpassW1'

As per your code. Test with the below:

```
import sys
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print ("Invalid args")
    return

password = sys.argv[1]
builder = 0

for c in password:
    builder += ord(c)

if builder == 1000 and len(password) == 10 and ord(password[1]) == 104:
    print ("correct")
else:
    print ("incorrect")

if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], 'lhngpassW1']
    main()
```